# How to support few thousand requests per second using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, concurrency, microservices

We are building micro service based architecture using spring boot. There are 6 micro-services, calling each other using `RestTemplate`.  When we load test those using 16GB, 4 Core machine, at max it supports 100 requests per second successfully. The CPU consumption goes beyond 100 all the time. We have tried setting up very high values for max connection and max threads. What else needs to be done to support few thousands requests per second?

Comment: What business do your micro services do?
I think it's better to use some monitor and tracing tools to analyze your services to discover what part of your service cost most of the cpu time, such as jconsole or visualvm. By the way, add connections or threads might be not a good way to improve performances, sometimes it would make your service slower.

Comment: Hi user10216953,
For eg. We call service A, it calls 4 other services. These 4 services hit S3 URL which returns static JSON. These services parse it and return it. Service A parse this response and return one of it. There's no extra processing as of now. It's all HTTP calling and parsing.